# iOS Zoom/Distort a particular part of the image using CIFilter

Tags: ios, image-processing, avfoundation, core-image, cifilter

The use case is to detect something in an image and zoom/distort-outward it as in you are looking through a magnifying glass.

Now I know the points where to zoom in but I need a CIFilter which can do the same.

Tried [CIHoleDistortion](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIHoleDistortion) but it did not work. The documentation seems to be fine to me and it should work but it only creates a black hole and the area around it is distorted.

```
let distortion = CIFilter(name: "CIHoleDistortion")
distortion.setValue(sourceImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
distortion.setValue(CIVector.init(cgPoint: CGPoint.init(x: 200, y: 200)), forKey: "inputCenter")
distortion.setValue(NSNumber.init(value: 100), forKey: "inputRadius")
```

Here are the test results:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a [`CIBumpDistortion`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIBumpDistortion)?

Comment: It worked. Still not sure how to use the convex and concave feature mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: I guess that means that it can have either a magnifying or minifying effect, depending on the `scale` parameter (`scale < 1.0` → concave; `scale > 1.0` → convex).

Comment: hmm I'll try it

Comment: please check this, if you can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55574172/avcapturevideopreviewlayer-add-overlays-and-capture-photo-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

Another (and maybe better) option is to use `CIGlassLozenge` filter:

1. Set `inputRefraction` to something slightly larger than 1 (e.g. 1.06)
2. Align both `inputPoint0` and `inputPoint1` with the coordinate of the zoom point
3. Play with the radius to get the desired effect. The attached example uses radius 1000.

[image]

If you want to play with this filter (and any other out of 250 CIFilters) in real time check this app out: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/filter-magic/id1594986951

Answer (score 0):

[CIBumpDistortion](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIBumpDistortion) as mentioned by Frank above, but the `scale` parameter actually works as follows: `scale < 0` -> concave; `scale > 0` -> convex.